# Asynchronous MVVM and design-time data

Tags: c#, design-patterns, asynchronous, mvvm, design-time-data

Today, I tried to implement View-Model asynchronously. I found [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx). In that moment I thought that it is not so easy I imagined...

I understand why it works. But unfortunately, it is impossible to use this code when I want to mock my design-time data of view-models with Blend (mocking using `SampleData.xaml`), because Blend doesn't allow to mock generic data this way. So I thought about some refactor like this one:

```
public IEnumerable<MyModelType> Data { get { return _task.Result; } }
private NotifyTaskCompletion<IEnumerable<MyModelType>> _task;
```

and calling `Data` from XAML instead of calling `Task.Result`.

Now I can mock everything again, but when I run the code, I didn't get my data the most times, because the Task had `WaitingForActivation` status. I don't understand the mechanism in each detail, but after a bit of Googling I got that I should use `async`/`await` syntax. It does make sense of course, but I can't do this because my `Data` is a property and it can't be `async`. And it doesn't make sense for me.

Do you have any workaround (or pretty solution) for my issue?

There is the second way of mocking design-time data using `IsInDesignMode` (part of MVVM Light). What do you think about this second way of mocking? Does it solve my problem? When I think about this solution, I think it works in so strange way: it should compile my program with entire code and setting this property to false, but the condition is still always checked. Isn't it? If not, how does it actualy work?